# sign in with google account

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I've added a "sign in with Google" button to my website, it signs in successfully (i know that because the button switches to "signed in" ), but I don't get the data from the Google account I need to continue, the console shows completely nothing. here's the code:

```
<head>
   <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content ="******************************************.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>

<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>

<script>
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); 
    }
</script>

<footer>
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
</footer>
```

I'm coding using php

Comment: the profile is empty object? or what do you mean with nothing? no console.log were called?

Comment: no console.log was called, but I could not tell if it's because the profile is empty